# github api get commits and commiters

Tags: c#, httpclient, github-api

I am trying to get the list of commiters
In beginning I ask GitHub API (v3) to get repositories:

```
https://api.github.com/users/{userName}/repos
```

ok, got some list, and I got there repository name, which I want to use to get all commits

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{userName}/{repoName}/commits
```

the address is correct, I get some information, but...
I don't know how to create classes, I don't understand this JSON structure

see the example on https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/

its something like this:

```
[0]
{
 "sha",
 "commit":{
       "commiter":{
        "name",
        "email",
        }
      }
}
```

so...  the commit class should have commit...?
I have tried something like this:

the Commit class

```
[DataContract(Name="commits")]
    public class Commit
    {
        [DataMember(Name="sha")]
        public string Sha{get;set;}
        [DataMember(Name="commiter")]
        public Commiter Commiter{get;set;}
    }
```

and the commiter class:

```
 [DataContract(Name="commiter")]
    public class Commiter
    {
        [DataMember(Name="name")]
        public string Name{get;set;}

        [DataMember(Name="email")]
        public string Email {get;set;}

        [DataMember(Name="date")]
        public string Date{get;set;}

        [DataMember(Name="message")]
        public string Message{get;set;}
    }
```

but the only result when I ask for commits is the SHA field from Commit class, the committer is always null

can someone help me :)?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this yourself rather than using a library such as Octokit?

Comment: I don't want to use whole library, i just want to send some 3 diffrent http requests, and then work on them on my application

Comment: Even if you only use it for a single request, it's still likely to be simpler than doing the same work yourself. Is there any particular reason *not* to use Octokit?

Comment: Separately, the URL you've given as a demo is incorrect - it should be https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits. Note that you've got a typo consistently - `commiter` instead of `committer`. (Note the double t). That may well be all that's wrong with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

For generate my POCO class I always use :
http://json2csharp.com/

It's automatic.
For your API it's :
    public class Author
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }

```
public class Committer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class Tree
{
    public string sha { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Verification
{
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public string signature { get; set; }
    public string payload { get; set; }
}

public class Commit
{
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public Committer committer { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Tree tree { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int comment_count { get; set; }
    public Verification verification { get; set; }
}

public class Author2
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string gravatar_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public string followers_url { get; set; }
    public string following_url { get; set; }
    public string gists_url { get; set; }
    public string starred_url { get; set; }
    public string subscriptions_url { get; set; }
    public string organizations_url { get; set; }
    public string repos_url { get; set; }
    public string events_url { get; set; }
    public string received_events_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool site_admin { get; set; }
}

public class Committer2
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string gravatar_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public string followers_url { get; set; }
    public string following_url { get; set; }
    public string gists_url { get; set; }
    public string starred_url { get; set; }
    public string subscriptions_url { get; set; }
    public string organizations_url { get; set; }
    public string repos_url { get; set; }
    public string events_url { get; set; }
    public string received_events_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool site_admin { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string sha { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string sha { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public Commit commit { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public string comments_url { get; set; }
    public Author2 author { get; set; }
    public Committer2 committer { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> parents { get; set; }
}
```